# Best optimal stopping theory textbook?

Tags: reference-request

What do you think is the best textbook on optimal stopping theory for someone on a late-stage-undergraduate level? The ones I've found online are Chow (1971) and Shiryaev & Aries (2007), and I suspect that Chow is the classic one. Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at K L Chung's A Course in Probability Theory?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No, I have not. Should I? Is it a prerequisite for optimal stopping theory?

Comment: It is one of the best books on Measure Theoretic Probability and it does discuss Optional sampling, Martingales etc.